# Зачем применяют данные псевдо-элементы почти к каждому блоку на многих сайтах?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Столкнулся с очень интересным фактом, что на многих сайтах к большинству основных блоков, которые составляют структуру html документа добавляется следующий непонятный для меня псевдо-элемент:

```
.some-block::after, .some-block::before{
  content: ""; 
  display: table;
}
```

Вопрос в следующем - зачем? В чём смысл сего действия, это же "колхоз", для чего его можно использовать, и какие в этом есть последствия?

Comment: Это вроде как для борьбы со схлопыванием родительских элементов, у которых дочерние элементы используют `float`. Как работает? ХЗ, `float`'ами не пользуюсь

Comment: для борьбы со " схлопыванием " прописывают несколько другой контент ! ;) По крайней мере в обязательном порядке прописывают clear : both ;

Comment: возможно, если Вы предоставите примеры сайтов, можно будет дать однозначный ответ

Comment: Хм, далеко ходить не пришлось - jQuery.com  -- .header .container .logo-evensts::before

Comment: @Muranx там не для `#logo-events` установлен `::after/::before`, а для элементов с классом `clearfix`.  Отключите  на jQuery.com  `.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after` и посмотрите, что будет с шапкой

Comment: сложилось 2 условия: они есть и есть любители все сделать на css =)

Comment: Хм, и понятно и не понятно . . . Почему бы на сайте jq.com просто не прописать .clearfix::after-ру {content:  " "; display: table; clear: both;} ? ? ? Зачем прописывать clear: both самим блокам , схлопывание которых мы хотим предотвратить? Я не понимаю

Comment: @Muranx абсолютно точный ответ "почему они сделали именно так" Вам дадут только разработчики конкретного сайта ))

Comment: Хм, ну это естественно, и очевидно! В любом случае вы мне помогли сэкономить некоторое время на обдумывание, поэтому спасибо! Хотя если честно я думал это какой-то повсеместный лайф хак среди разработчиков веб сайтов, потому-что видел подобное поведение ооочень много где! Алекс , если не трудно, то в двух словах. . . Как отблагодарить вас с ответ? Хотя это даже не ответ, а почему-то "коментарий"

Comment: В свое время, когда не было альтернатив это и костылями не выглядело, это +- кроссбраузерно и достаточно много что можно ими сделать, а иной раз и по сей день некоторые вещи без них не сделать, разве что вложенными элементами

Answer (score 0):

Псевдоэлементы `:before` и `:after` могут быть полезны в множестве случаев.

Массовый характер получили из-за очистки `float: left` и `float: right`.

Стандартное применение:

```
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

Однако, использовать их можно в множестве иных ситуаций. Приведу простой пример:

```css
a {
  position: relative;
}

a:before {
  content: attr(title);
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 4px 4px 4px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #333 transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

a:hover:before,
a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" title="Подсказка">Ссылка</a>
```

Таким способом выводят часто количество товаров в корзине, подсказки, иконки и прочие вещи.

Не смотря на возможность использования иных способов избежать последствий стилей `float`, например, при помощи `overflow: hidden`, все равно у многих разработчиков это идет как стандарт. И, даже в современных реалиях, когда на замену старым конструкциям пришли новые варианты, тот же `flexbox` или `grid`, псевдоэлементы продолжают часто встречаться именно в целях борьбы с проблемой нулевой высоты контейнера.

В указанном примере на http://jquery.com/ используется clearfix из 2011 года. Все подробности можно найти в [первоисточнике](http://nicolasgallagher.com/better-float-containment-in-ie/).

```
.clearfix::before,
.clearfix::after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix::after {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

Он был актуален для тех времен, когда разработчики, скрипя зубами, обеспечивали поддержку IE6. По прошествии времени, уже на этапе поддержки IE8, конструкцию упростили до той, которая показа в начале ответа.

Причина, по которой разработчики упомянутого сайта воткнули `clear: both` для родителя мне не понятна. В данной конструкции он ни на что не влияет. По крайней мере в современных браузерах.

Comment: Эмм, ну то, что вы показали в примере с ссылкой, это моя "стихия", я сам очень часто использую псевдо-элементы для украшения каких-нибудь карточек товара, или иконок с фото. Но именно на мой вопрос я всё-таки не получил ответа! А именно, почему в классе .clearfix:after прописывается лишь content:""; и display: table; А вот уже clear:both прописывают именно блокам, схлопывание которых нужно избежать? Почему просто не написать класс .clearfix:after{dis.:table;content:"";clear:both}? Зачем разделать эти два события? Если вы не понял, о чем я, то тогда сайт jQuery.com вам объяснит суть!

Comment: Alexey Giryayev просто зайдите на jQuery.com в инспектор, и посмотрите на любой блок с :after и :before , суть в том, что в афтерах и бефорах есть лишь  content:""; display:table; А вот уже clear:both прописывается в качестве свойства родительскому блоку. . .

Comment: @Muranx дополнил ответ, для будущих поколений. Хотя, вопрос бы стоило задавать чутка иначе, если вас интересовал конкретный сайт и конкретное свойство у родителя.